# Regex pattern BBCode to Wiki Notation, C#

Tags: c#, regex, wiki, bbcode

I am tasked with converting BB code to WIKI notation and thanx to the many examples on SO I have cracked most of the tougher nuts. This is my first foray into Regex and I'm trying to learn it as I go (*I would prefer stringbuilder but it doesnt seem to work with BB code*). I have 4 items I need replaced that I cannot seem to create the proper pattern to identify: (*original string on left, what I need on right after double dash*)

[image]

the first item is a problem child because the wiki engine adds a new line where the spaces are. It is not a separate field but part of a larger string so I cant TRIM() it. I am currently using

```
result = result.Replace("[b]", "*").Replace("[/b]", "*");
```

the img issue is a need to somehow include the attributes if possible in the given format.

for the last 2 I am stumped. I have used

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"<a .*?href=['""](.+?)['""].*?>(.+?)</a>");
        foreach (var match in r.Matches(multistring).Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Index))
        {
            string href = match.Groups[1].Value;
            string txt = match.Groups[2].Value;
            string wikilink = "[" + txt + "|" + href + "]";
            sb.Remove(match.Groups[2].Index, match.Groups[2].Length);
            sb.Insert(match.Groups[2].Index, wikilink);
        }
```

in the past for HTML but cant seem to refactor it for my current needs. Suggestions, links to resources, all would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
solved the img issue, though it's not pretty and I still risk removing a closing [/img] tag that may not be caught earlier. The [img] code is fairly consistent, so I used:

```
                Regex imgparser = new Regex(@"\[img[^\]]*\]([^\[]*)");
                foreach (var itag in imgparser.Matches(multistring).Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Index))
                {
                    string isrc = itag.Groups[1].Value;
                    string wikipic = itag.ToString().Replace("[img ", "!" + isrc).Replace("width=", "!width=").Replace("height=", ",height=").Replace("]" + isrc, string.Empty);
                    result = result.Replace(itag.ToString(), wikipic);
                }
                result = result.Replace("[/img]", "!");
```

Comment: 3) [`\[url=(mailto:[^]]*)].*?\[/url]` -> `[$1]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5burl%3d(mailto%3a%5b%5e%5d%5d*)%5d.*%3f%5c%5b%2furl%5d&i=%5bb%5dRaynor+Schein++%5b%2fb%5d%0d%0a%5bimg+width%3d130+height%3d30%5datt6387%5b%2fimg%5d%0d%0a%5burl%3dmailto%3amc%23example.com%5dmc%40example.com%5b%2furl%5d%0d%0a%5burl%3dhttp%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%2f%5dmy+link+text%5b%2furl%5d&r=%5b%241%5d). 4) `\[url=(http[^]]*)](.*?)\[/url]` --> `[$2|$1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a little example for the last case :

```
 string str1 = "[url=http://aadqsdqsd]link[/url]";
 var pattern = @"^\[url=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]$";
 var match = Regex.Match(str1, pattern);
 var result = string.Format("[{0}| {1}]", match.Groups[2].Value, match.Groups[1].Value);
 //[link| http://aadqsdqsd]
```

Is it what you want ?

**EDIT**

if you want to match a larger string you can do :

```
    var strTomatch = "[url=http://1]link1[/url][url=http://2]link2[/url]" + Environment.NewLine +
                     "[url = http://3]link3[/url]" + Environment.NewLine +
                     "[url=http://4]link4[/url]";

    var match = Regex.Match(strTomatch, @"\[url\s*=\s*(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        var result = string.Format("[{0}| {1}]", match.Groups[2].Value, match.Groups[1].Value);
        Debug.WriteLine(result);
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
```

*Output*

```
[link1| http://1]
[link2| http://2]
[link3| http://3]
[link4| http://4]
```

Comment: thank you for the response. the pattern definitely does catch what I want. Is there someway to add a wild card(s) to the start and end of the regex pattern? the str1 in this case is part of a larger string and it doesnt match anything if there are characters before and/or after the string parameter. just trying to understand, thank you in advance